# Automatic conversion of UML diagram from NClass to yEd?

Tags: uml, file-conversion

I can't find a way to automatically convert a NClass-generated file into yEd...I wanted to know if some of you guys have ever come across this issue - I am not optimistic about it, I just wanted the last confirmation before I start converting it by hand... :(